# What is the general definition of thickness of a strange attractor?

Tags: classical-mechanics, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems

Disclaimer: This question is cross posted on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3252277/) because I don't know which site is more appropriate for this question.

---

In [Chaosbook](http://chaosbook.org), at page 56, it is asked to find the *thickness* of Rössler strange attractor, by some means. However, up to this point, the book have only defined the thickness of an Henon map, as the coefficient of the $x_{n-1}$ term in the evolution of a specific sequence.

**Question:**

What is the general definition of *thickness* of a [strange attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor)?

Edit: I'm using the version 13.5 of the book (the unstable version).

Comment: Could you link to the specific version of the Chaos Book you're using? I fail to find the exercise you're talking about.

Comment: @stafusa because of the way how the website is designed, I cannot give a direct link to the book, but in the home page of the book, open unstable -> experimental page, and you should find the version 13.5 of the book (the only version on that page). I'm using that one.

Answer (score 1):

*Thickness* isn't a technical term here, but rather it's being used in its everyday sense.

So, you could simply take the lobe of the attractor close to the plane $x,y$ and consider a Poincaré section (or even a projection) perpendicular to that plane to see why the attractor is described as a [stretched and folded ribbon](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Rossler_attractor#Topological_description).